# Creating bar chart in R

Tags: r, time-series, bar-chart

I want to plot overlapping bar plot in R.

Actually I did a stacked plot but it does not say much.

```
 library(ggplot2)
 library(dplyr)

df_new2 %>% mutate(Gender=as.factor(Gender)) %>% 
group_by(Year,Gender) %>% summarize(mean=mean(Life_expectancy)) 
%>% ggplot() +
aes(x=Year, y=mean, group=Gender, col=Gender) +
geom_bar(stat="identity")+
labs(title="Life expectancy by gender from 2015-2021", x="Year", 
 y="Mean of life expectancy")
```

I tried this. But I got something very weird.

```
  library(ggplot2)
  library(dplyr)

  df_new2 %>% mutate(Gender=as.factor(Gender)) %>% 
  group_by(Year,Gender) %>% summarize(mean=mean(Life_expectancy)) 
  %>% ggplot() +
  aes(x=Year, y=mean, group=Gender, col=Gender, factor(Year), 
  fill=factor(Gender)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  labs(title="Life expectancy by gender from 2015-2021", 
  x="Year", y="Mean of life expectancy")
```